# Parceler + Realm + Kotlin: error: cannot find symbol

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, parceler

I'm trying to use Parceler with a realm class created in Kotlin. When I try to build my app, it fails.

Here's my Realm class:

```
Parcel(implementations = [com_companyname_models_realm_objects_kotlin_PlayerRealmProxy::class],
    value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
    analyze = [Player::class])
open class Player : RealmObject() {
  ...
}
```

I'm including parceler in my project using gradle:

```
implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.12'
annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.12'
```

Here's the error I get:

```
error: cannot find symbol
@org.parceler.Parcel(implementations = {com_companyname_models_realm_objects_kotlin_PlayerRealmProxy.class}, value = org.parceler.Parcel.Serialization.BEAN, analyze = {com.companyname.models.realm.objects.kotlin.Player.class})
```

Using Realm 6.1.0. Also tried 7.0 with the same results.

The realm docs for Parceler support are very out of date, and don't even mention that you need the implementations and analyze properties wrapped in an array. Can anyone out there help me figure this out?